# unable to extract minute from timestamp in oracle query

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm getting an invalid identifier for the minute extraction in my query. What am I doing wrong here?

```
 SELECT service_name,
         a.app_context_id,
         domain_cdc_status,
         MAX (
            (SELECT EXTRACT (minute, TO_TIMESTAMP (MAX (updated_at)))
               FROM domain_cdc
              WHERE     app_context_id = a.app_context_id
                    AND domain_cdc_status = a.domain_cdc_status
                    AND domain_cdc_status IN ('DONE', 'PENDING', 'DONE', 'NEW')))
         - MIN (
              (SELECT EXTRACT (minute, TO_TIMESTAMP ( (updated_at)))
                 FROM domain_cdc
                WHERE app_context_id = a.app_context_id
                      AND domain_cdc_status = a.domain_cdc_status
                      AND domain_cdc_status IN
                             ('DONE', 'PENDING', 'DONE', 'NEW')))
            AS diff,
         COUNT (*)
    FROM    domain_cdc a
         INNER JOIN
            application_status b
         ON a.app_context_id = b.app_context_id
   WHERE a.app_context_id IN (2334, 2333, 2332)
GROUP BY a.app_context_id, domain_cdc_status, service_name
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: If you want the difference of two date/time points expressed in units of minute, then extract() is NOT going to do this. If the total interval between to points in time was 1 year 1 month 1 day and 12 minutes, "extract minute" would report 12. My guess is this in not what you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a comma:

```
SELECT EXTRACT( MINUTE FROM SYSTIMESTAMP ) FROM dual
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/34930

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions050.htm

The comments point out that MINUTE can not be extracted from a DATE value. Why? I don't know. The documentation for EXTRACT is unclear. It can be extracted from a TIMESTAMP value. I've changed the example appropriately.

The reason TO_TIMESTAMP doesn't work is because it operates only on character data, so your date is implicitly converted to a VARCHAR2 first, then to the timestamp. My guess is your NLS settings for the default date format do not include the time component, so that intermediate VARCHAR2 has a 0 minute.

Assuming your updated_at column is a DATE datatype, I'd suggest this:

```
SELECT EXTRACT( MINUTE FROM CAST( updated_at AS TIMESTAMP )) ...
```

Comment: when I remove that, I get missing right parenthesis.

Comment: @eaolson `MINUTE` can't be extracted from `SYSDATE`. Instead `TIMESTAMP`is required. Otherwise you're on the spot!

Comment: So the tinestamp conversion im using should work then. But its not.

Comment: okay I once I use the timestamp conversion, I get a 0 `SELECT EXTRACT( MINUTE FROM to_timestamp(sysdate) ) FROM dual`

Answer (score 0):

try use

```
SELECT service_name,
         a.app_context_id,
         domain_cdc_status,
         MAX (
            (SELECT EXTRACT (minute FROM TO_TIMESTAMP (MAX (updated_at)))
               FROM domain_cdc
              WHERE     app_context_id = a.app_context_id
                    AND domain_cdc_status = a.domain_cdc_status
                    AND domain_cdc_status IN ('DONE', 'PENDING', 'DONE', 'NEW')))
         - MIN (
              (SELECT EXTRACT (minute FROM TO_TIMESTAMP ( (updated_at)))
                 FROM domain_cdc
                WHERE app_context_id = a.app_context_id
                      AND domain_cdc_status = a.domain_cdc_status
                      AND domain_cdc_status IN
                             ('DONE', 'PENDING', 'DONE', 'NEW')))
            AS diff,
         COUNT (*)
    FROM    domain_cdc a
         INNER JOIN
            application_status b
         ON a.app_context_id = b.app_context_id
   WHERE a.app_context_id IN (2334, 2333, 2332)
GROUP BY a.app_context_id, domain_cdc_status, service_name
ORDER BY 1
```

Also your field `update_at` should be timestamp type because `SELECT EXTRACT( MINUTE FROM to_timestamp(sysdate) ) FROM dual` and `SELECT EXTRACT( MINUTE FROM systimestamp ) FROM dual` return different results

Comment: thanks. This query does run when I add rownum = 1 after DONE, PENDING etc.. But I'm getting 0 and blanks in the diff column.

Comment: `extract(minute from (x - y) )` does NOT convert the entire difference into minute units. I think your expectation might not be met through `extract()`

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify what you are really seeking from this query (e.g. no "expected result"), but it appears you want a difference between 2 temporal values expressed as minutes.

You also don't tell us what type the field `updated_at` is. It appears to be a date because you apply `to_timestamp()` to it.

So, assuming `updated_at` is a date type, and you want the difference expressed in minutes, then I would suggest the following:

```
SELECT
      service_name
    , a.app_context_id
    , domain_cdc_status
    , ( MAX(updated_at) - MIN( updated_at) ) * (24*60) AS diff /* in minutes */
    , COUNT(*)
FROM domain_cdc a
      INNER JOIN application_status b
                  ON a.app_context_id = b.app_context_id
      INNER JOIN domain_cdc c
                  ON app_context_id = a.app_context_id
                  AND domain_cdc_status = a.domain_cdc_status
                  AND domain_cdc_status IN ('DONE', 'PENDING', 'DONE', 'NEW')
WHERE a.app_context_id IN (2334, 2333, 2332)
GROUP BY
      a.app_context_id
    , domain_cdc_status
    , service_name
ORDER BY
      service_name
;
```